# What can cause a jump in tag points?

Tags: support, tags, tag-score

I am following the points of [top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/typescript/topusers) on the TypeScript tag pretty closely, and I jot them down in a spreadsheet almost daily (don't judge; yes, I know I am obsessed).

I couldn't help, but notice that between Friday (2018-08-10) and Monday (2018-08-13) one user had a huge increase in points (204 points, from 2921 to 3125). The weird part is there is nothing in the user activity to support this jump.

He got below 200 points on each of those days and I am just unsure where these points could be coming from. Also it's very uncharacteristic of the amount of points the user usually earns on this tag (an average of about 2-3 points per day over the past 30 days).

Does anyone have any ideas where such a lange jump could come from? Could this be the sign of a bug in the point update system?

Comment: Related: *[Wikipediholic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikipediholic)*, *[Wikibreak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WB)*, and *[How do I prevent a Stack Overflow addiction?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91609)*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen It's like they know me :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073705/property-catch-does-not-exist-on-type-observableany) would be a large part of that.

As you can see, a user edited that tag into this question. Since the user you mention has an answer with a score of 201 on that question, that answer now counts towards their [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript) score.

There's likely another, smaller point answer that had the same happen to it, to add up to the point difference you noticed. Or, the other couple points could've just been upvotes to older posts.

Comment: 10x for the answer, that was probably it.

Answer (score 5):

Quite a few things, but we need to respect user's privacy, too. Could be ..

- Another account owned by the same person was merged into their normal account
- A post they wrote with community wiki status was converted to non-wiki, so they got quite a bit of rep from it (my rep would go up significantly if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806585/why-is-linux-called-a-monolithic-kernel/1806597#1806597) had that status removed, as an example).
- Other back-end administrative things I'm probably forgetting

... if the rep history works out from what's on the profile, there's no cause for alarm, it's *very* likely one of the two things I noted above. If you think something is just way off in left field, it's better if you simply contact us directly to have a look. While I'm sure it's okay in this case, linking to someone's profile on meta draws *a lot of attention* to them, and can result in a pile-on (negative) effect.